# Axios not returning network response, resolving despite 422 error

Tags: javascript, axios

So this is driving me nuts because it was working at one point, and I cannot find anything I changed that would make it not work.

Here is my simple axios post request. Based on my debugging, this is successfully making the network request and the server is returning a 422 error, which I expect (testing invalid login credentials). However, when attempting to log the axios reponse to the console, I get "undefined". It is also returning a resolved promise.

```js
const login = (loginParams) => {
  return axiosLoggedOut.post("/login", loginParams);
};
```

Here is the code for the axios instance I am using. I am only intercepting the request in this, and I know the request it making it to the server, so I don't think the issue would be in here:

```js
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosLoggedOut = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost",
  withCredentials: true,
});

const requestTypes = ['post', 'put', 'delete'];

const onRequest = (config) => {
  if (requestTypes.includes(config.method) && !Cookies.get('XSRF-TOKEN')) {
    return setCSRFToken().then(() => config);
  }

  return config;
}

const setCSRFToken = () => {
  return axiosLoggedOut.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie'); 
}

axiosLoggedOut.interceptors.request.use(onRequest, null);

export default axiosLoggedOut;
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: The axios. get makes an async request and returns a promise. it returns undefined cuz why u r trying to do is sync but axios is async

Comment: @KickButtowski I know it returns a promise. I am returning that promise to a react query mutation. The issue is that the promise is resolving despite an error and has an undefined response.

Comment: @smritz I am not sure what the reason is but I can tell that some APIs can return only http status code and nothing else. Can you confirm that making that request using curl gives you any meaningful response?

Comment: @TwistedOwl Yeah, I have confirmed that it is returning a 422 status along with an object with information about what the error is. Even if it was just the status code though, I would expect the axios promise to reject.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same error.

When I receive a 422 error, it resolves the promise with an undefned AxiosResponse object and does not fall in the catch.

It is very annoying and I am convinced it must be an error with Axios.
If anyone figures out what is the real problem here, please share.

Until that, here is my workaround, using old but reliable Fetch API:

**I went from this**

```
function changePaymentMethod(
  contractId: number,
  bank_id: number
): Promise<AxiosResponse> {   
  return apiV2.put(`contracts/${contractId}`, { bank_id });
}
```

**To this**

```
function changePaymentMethod(
  contractId: number,
  bank_id: number
): Promise<Response> { 
  return fetch(`contracts/${contractId}`, {
    method: "PUT",
    body: JSON.stringify({bank_id}),
  });
}
```